# How to manage loading incase of multiple AJAX call in HTML page in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have loading div as following:
CSS:

```
.loader {
    border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 8px solid gray;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loader"></div>
<div>
    <button onclick="generateOrder();">Create Order</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function generateOrder() {
     $('.loader').css('display', 'block');
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: oDataUri,
            data: jsonPO,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                    AddProducts(data.results[i].ProductID, data.results[i].ProductName)
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
        reloadGridData();   //it will call ajax and reload all data.
        $('.loader').css('display', 'none');                                                                        
}

function AddProducts(productID, productName) {
     //$('.loader').css('display', 'block');
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: oDataUri,
            data: jsonPO,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                    //more AJAX call with async: false
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
        //$('.loader').css('display', 'none');
}
```

In Above case, loading is working fine in Mozila Firefox but when I am trying to use in Google Chrome, it doesn't work.

I can't set Async to True. Also I have multiple Ajax call.

Please suggest me solution of it.

Comment: it's not multiple ajax calls. it's nested ajax calls. plus they are in `for` loops. there's no way to know which call will finish last. there's basically..no way to do that. why do you have such a complex ajax call chaining. is it really necessary to go 3rd level. and that too in a loop? you can make a movie out of it! **Ajaxception**

Comment: @MridulKashyap It is just part of example. I have another call also. Let me add one more line. `reloadGridData()`

Comment: @MridulKashyap I know it's complex chain. But in some circumstances, I must use this. Please suggest.

Comment: ok. i'll post the answer with what i have in my mind.

Comment: @MridulKashyap Please note above code is working in Firefox. It just create problem in Chrome. It should work in both browser.

Comment: the implementation of certain aspects might be different among browsers. we can fight that we want the same thing in every browser. instead we have to change the code to make it compatible in every browser. as harsh as it sounds, it's still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only 2 way i can think of are:

1. find which ajax calls finishes in the end. and in the success block of it call `$('.loader').css("display":"none");`.
2. register an even when the data that you must have before showing the page is available. and create an event listener to listen to it. when the data is available the event will be fired. the listener will listen and call `$('.loader').css("display":"none");` and deregister the event.

that's all folks!

Comment: Option 1: What if I have to manipulate some information after Ajax success call. In my case I have few information need to manipulate. Option 2: Can you please suggest me example or way? I don't about this.

Comment: Hi, I have applied your concept. It looks fine if I check by debugger but when I run it without debugging, it doesn't show. Do I need to set time out? If so, can you please suggest me where to set?

Answer (score 1):

Why note use the jQuery `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` methods to run your code.

[ajaxStart Document](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

- This is a global event handler which gets fired when ever an ajax call is occurred. The same principle goes to ajaxStop as well. You could search ajaxStop in google to get the documentation. Pretty easy to use.

Comment: I don't about that. Can you please suggest me any link of example or way? That can help to make the code much better.

Answer (score 1):

Is just a dirty quick suggestion, not a pretty solution at all (and no tested):

1. Declare a global var to store the total ajax calls count (without async), and initiate the loader and the first ajax call

   ```
   ajax_count = 1;
   $ajax({
     // ...
   });
   ```
2. Increase the ajax call count on  success:

   ```
   ajax_count = data.results.length;
   ```

   2.1. and decrease ajax_count and check if is the less or equal to 0:

   ```
   ajax_count--;
   if (ajax_count <= 0) {
     $('.loader').css("display":"none");
   }
   ```
3. Increase the ajax_count in the second ajax success callback calls level:

   ```
   ajax_count += data.results.length;
   ```

   3.1. and decrease ajax_count and check if is the less or equal to 0:

   ```
   ajax_count--;
   if (ajax_count <= 0) {
     $('.loader').css("display":"none");
   }
   ```
4. On the ajax third level success callback decrease and compare ajax_count too
5. Refactor the code as you want (encapsulate check, handle possible error - decrease and check on error callback too, or use the complete callback, ...)